# Elasticsearch: Change root url from / to /elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, dns, url-routing, elasticsearch-6

I am setting up an elasticsearch cluster and I want to set the domain url to `<domain_name>/elastic`

Currently, when I go to `<domain_name>/elastic`, elasticsearch thinks `/elastic` as the name of the index.

I haven't found any documentation on how to set the root url context for elatsicsearch. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to front your ES with a web server such as nginx or apache in order to achieve that.

Comment: I have nginx routing `/elastic` to the elasticsearch client but the problem is that elasticsearch sees the url as `<domain_name>/elastic` and thinks `/elastic` is the name of an index that is being searched for.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are searching through internet how to do the similar thing in Kubernetes when using ingress with path other then `/` it can be done using annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:  /` like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  rules:
  - host: k8s-master
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: elasticsearch
          servicePort: 9200
        path: /elastic
```

It will map *http://k8s-master:ingress_port/elastic* internally on root context of `elasticsearch` service and `index_not_found_exception` error is solved.

Comment: Note that Spring boot elasticsearch cannot connect to an elasticsearch instance that runs under (such) a path. Instead of the solution here, we're now trying to run elasticsearch on a subdomain.

Comment: what if we have something already running on root (/), in that we need to change the base url of ES

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer from cgrim did lead me to the right direction, I had an issue where I was not able to search on any of the indices. Instead, this rewrite target worked for me.

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  rules:
  - host: k8s-host
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: elasticsearch-master
          servicePort: 9200
        path: /elastic(/|$)(.*)
```

This solution will still map `/path` to the root and resolve the `index_not_found_exception` error.

Answer (score 0):

Put like this in nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location /elastic {
        rewrite /elastic/(.*) /$1  break;
        proxy_redirect  off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9200/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).