# fluentd to elasticsearch via kubernetes-ingress

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd, nginx-ingress

I have configured ElasticSearch on a Kubernetes cluster. In Kubernetes cluster for application, I have fluentd configured, using [THIS](https://github.com/kiwigrid/helm-charts/blob/master/charts/fluentd-elasticsearch/values.yaml) helm chart, with the following parameters:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: FLUENTD_ARGS
      value: --no-supervisor -q
    - name: OUTPUT_HOST
      value: x.x.x.x
    - name: OUTPUT_PORT
      value: "80"
    - name: OUTPUT_PATH
      value: /elastic
    - name: LOGSTASH_PREFIX
      value: logstash
    - name: OUTPUT_SCHEME
      value: http
    - name: OUTPUT_SSL_VERIFY
      value: "false"
    - name: OUTPUT_SSL_VERSION
      value: TLSv1_2
    - name: OUTPUT_TYPE_NAME
      value: _doc
    - name: OUTPUT_BUFFER_CHUNK_LIMIT
      value: 2M
    - name: OUTPUT_BUFFER_QUEUE_LIMIT
      value: "8"
    - name: OUTPUT_LOG_LEVEL
      value: info
```

In ElasticSearch cluster I have nginx-ingress controller configured and I want fluentd to send logs to Elasticsearch via this nginx ingress. In "OUTPUT_HOST" I am using nginx-ingress public IP. In "OUTPUT_PORT" I have used "80" as nginx is listening on 80.

I am getting the following error in fluentd:

```
2019-11-06 07:16:46 +0000 [warn]: [elasticsearch] failed to flush the buffer. 
retry_time=40 next_retry_seconds=2019-11-06 07:17:18 +0000 chunk="596a7f6afffad60f2b28a5e13f" 
error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchOutput::RecoverableRequestFailure error="could not push logs to Elasticsearch cluster (
{:host=>\"x.x.x.x\", :port=>80, :scheme=>\"http\", :path=>\"/elastic\"}): [405] 
{\"error\":\"Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/] and method [POST], allowed: [HEAD, GET, DELETE]\",\"status\":405}"
```

I can guess by looking at the log, it is considering "/elastic" as index.

A mentioned [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50988363/elasticsearch-change-root-url-from-to-elastic) is used the annotation "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /" but problem persists.

After this, I changed nginx-ingress to listen to calls at "/" instead of "/elastic". changed "OUTPUT_PATH" in fluentD config too.

I could see the error I was getting earlier is gone but I would still like to use "/elastic" instead of "/". I am not sure what nginx config I need to change to achieve this. Please help me here.

After this, I got a "request entity too large" error which was resolved by adding - "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m" in annotations. By default its 1M and for fluentD by default it's 2M. It was bound to fail.

Now I am getting errors like:

```
2019-11-06 10:01:08 +0000 [warn]: dump an error event: 
error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ConcatFilter::TimeoutError error="Timeout flush: kernel:default" location=nil tag="kernel" 
time=2019-11-06 10:01:08.267224927 +0000 record=
{
    "transport"=>"kernel", 
    "syslog_facility"=>"0", 
    "syslog_identifier"=>"kernel", 
    "boot_id"=>"6e4ca7b1c1a11b74151a12979", 
    "machine_id"=>"89436ac666fa120304f2077f3bf2", 
    "priority"=>"6", 
    "hostname"=>"gke-dev--node-pool", 
    "message"=>"
      cbr0: port 9(vethe75a241b) entered disabled statedevice vethe75a241b left promiscuous mode
      cbr0: port 9(vethe75a241b) entered disabled state
      IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth630f6cb0: link is not ready
      IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth630f6cb0: link becomes ready
      cbr0: port 9(veth630f6cb0) entered blocking state
      cbr0: port 9(veth630f6cb0) entered disabled statedevice veth630f6
      cb0 entered promiscuous mode
      cbr0: port 9(veth630f6cb0) entered blocking state
      cbr0: port 9(veth630f6cb0) entered forwarding state", 
"source_monotonic_timestamp"=>"61153348174"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding the nginx config: [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) is official documentation regarding the Rewrite. You can adjust it to your needs alongside `OUTPUT_PATH` in fluentD config as you already mentioned.
2. Regarding the error event: The timeout flush just indicates that a flush has happened. Use the `timeout_label` to process entries where the flush has occurred. It's usually better to dispatch the message instead of emitting an error event.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Mark . I am trying out new things with the Hints I got from your message. Will update this thread in a while

Comment: Hey Mark, so what I did is added following config in kibana: `kibanaConfig:
   kibana.yml: |
     server.basePath: /kibana
     server.rewriteBasePath: true
`  and this annotation in nginx-ingress resource - `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /kibana` ....... After this I was able to achieve what I wanted and errors were gone too .. elastic is listening on `/`